# Django form fields not rendering

Tags: python, django, forms

I was trying to customize the 'User' model present in Django by adding a few fields via forms.py. But the issue is when I was rendering the form, those fields aren't coming into effect. Please can you figure out the error.

forms.py

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Enter your name.', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'first_name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'last_name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}), max_length=254, help_text='Enter a valid email address')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserCreationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        print()
        for field in form:
            print(field)
            print()
        return render(request, 'register.html', context=context)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            redirect('login/')
        else:
            E = []
            for error in form.errors:
                E.append(error)
            return HttpResponse(E)
```

So whenever I was doing a GET request for the registration page. All the fields are not printing. Thus are not showing when we render the html page.

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" autofocus required id="id_username">

<input type="password" name="password1" autocomplete="new-password" required id="id_password1">

<input type="password" name="password2" autocomplete="new-password" required id="id_password2">

[19/Apr/2020 20:30:20] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5012
```

This is what is getting printed on the terminal (the fields of the form).
Why are all the fields (custom made) not getting loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still using `UserCreationForm` in the view instead of a new `CreateUserForm`.

Comment: Oh yes!! Thank you soo much. Thank you for your help. Sometimes we think so much and the error lies in such simple things. xD